# Resharper cannot rename files when Git version control is applied

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

I have a Git version controlled solution in VS 2013 with several projects. Some of the projects are outside of the solution folder and thus are not controlled by Git.

I noticed that for those projects that are outside of the solution folder Resharper 8 class name refactoring fails with the 'file is read-only' error. It also fails to apply "Rename file to match the class name" command.

All works fine for the projects that are IN the solution folder and are controlled by Git.

Is this a known issue of VS or Resharper? Or is it considered a normal flow, and the files must be renamed manually?

**UPDATE**

Another interesting issue, Resharper cannot modify those files' content as well. So if I want to comment a line using Resharper's command, it won't until I start editing the file manually in VS.

Comment: Could you please go to Tools | Options | Source Control | Plug-in Selection | Set "Current source control plug-in" to "None"? Then try again.

Comment: @Alexander, yes, this solves the issue, but I need Git to be on though.

Comment: Do you use this embedded VS Git extension or standalone Git client like SourceTree?

Comment: @Alexander, I use VS 2013 own Git in Team Explorer dialog to commit changes AND 3rd party Git client to examine the history.

Comment: Could you please specify 3rd party Git client and the version of Git server? We need it to reproduce the issue on our side. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alexander, SmartGit and TortoiseGit, Git version is 1.9.0.

Comment: We have invesigated the issue (related ticket in YouTrack http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-338404) and it looks like a bug in VS Git extension. We will mail MS team about this.

Comment: It sill looks like the only fix (work around) is to "set current source control plugin" to "none": http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/24790716--Refactoring-failed-Files-still-read-only-error-message-when-applying-Quick-Fix Anyone found a fix that doesn't require you to do that?

Comment: Same problem even this many years on. The answer so far: have you tried turning it off and back on again? Close VS, Open VS, then I can rename the folder. How wonderfully annoying is this? It is 100 percent annoying.