# Cannot rename files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I cannot rename files in Solution Explorer any more, and I get no errors/dialogs. It just leaves the file with the original name. This also impacts folders (I can't rename them) and I also cannot cut/paste files & folders. Copy & delete work fine.

I've tried logging devenv.exe and but [nothing shows up](http://pastebin.com/pmp3n93q). I've tried the `/ResetAddin`, `/ResetSettings`, `/ResetSkipPkgs` & `/rootsuffix exp` switches and they do not help.

However running with `/SafeMode` rename works fine.

I have tried disabling all the add-ins that I can but that doesn't help. I have turned source control to none, yet that didn't help either.

[Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432/en-gb) is installed & [ReSharper is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409312/resharper-cannot-rename-files-when-git-version-control-is-applied).

---

I tried uninstalling [Multilingual App Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/bg127574.aspx), [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) & [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) and that solved the problem. Then I reinstalled all of them and the problem didn't turn up again :/

Comment: Maybe the file is renamed, just not in the directory or project that you're expecting.

Comment: @Dialecticus nope - confirmed in Explorer that the file is not renamed

Comment: I'd bet at least a dollar or two that this is related to your source control plug-in. Try turning it off. The `/safemode` switch is disabling *extensions* as well as add-ins. Turn off all of the extensions and see if your problem goes away. If it does, start turning them back on one-by-one until you find the culprit.

Comment: @CodyGray - I've tried setting source control to none - didn't fix it. I've tried disabling all extensions I can - didn't fix it. Going through the process of uninstalling extensions now.

Comment: I had the exact same issue though had ReSharper installed (8.2). However after uninstalling the Multilingual App Toolkit, it all seemed to work again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **Multilingual App Toolkit** seems to be the culprit. I had the same issues as the OP, couldn't change file/folder names, move files etc.

I discovered that running Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 with the /SafeMode switch cured the problem temporarily.

Looking for a more permanent solution, I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, but that didn't fix the problem.  But once I removed the  Multilingual App Toolkit the problem went away..

[EDIT]

It appears that reinstalling the Multilingual App Toolkit solves the problem too.

[image]

Comment: thank you so very much - it was the root of so many other issues I was having!!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to remove the MAT. Just uninstalling it, then reinstalling it will do the trick AND you will still have the awesomesauce of the MAT 
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/06/fix-for-being-unable-to-rename-files.html